# Wordpress - get short description of recent post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have wordpress website and I want to get recent posts. So I use loop

```
<?php $args = array( 'numberposts' => '3' );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);?>

<ul>
    <?php foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){?>
        <li>
            <?php echo '<div class="textoverlay">
                <a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '"><h1>' .  $recent["post_title"].'</h1></a>
                    <p>'.get_post_field('post_content', $recent["ID"]).'</p>
            </div> ';
            if ( has_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"]) ) {
                echo  get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"],'thumbnail');
            } ?>
        </li>
        <?php
    }?>
</ul>
```

I use get_post_field for post description, but I see full description. So is it possible to get short description of post by ID ?  For example first 10 words ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$content = get_post_field('post_content', $recent["ID"]);
$content = strip_tags($content);
echo substr($content, 0, 10);
```

just use [substr](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_substr.asp) for first 10 words